# desktopdock or stardock in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, desktop, dock

Is there any opensource/sample application in qt/c++, just like desktopdock or objectdock..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XQDE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xqde/) is an OSX-style dock written in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the demos and examples section of the documentation:
[QT Demos](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/demos.html)
[QT Examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html)
The demos are slightly larger than the examples, while the examples are focused on showing a specific feature - and good Qt programming. There's also the tutorial, [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/tutorials.html), which covers the entire development of two simple apps.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. but,I don't need just sample application for any widget. I need sample for specific desktopdock or objectdock kind of application.
otherwise adding into your list, there are lots of widgets/sample applications at http://www.qt-apps.org even at google code, but I am not able to find even sample design-architecture for this kind of application at anywhere...:(